# Receive data from a client/server doesn't work

Tags: python, sockets

I developed a small Python program which should receive and output data from another client or server. However, I get an error message which is unknown to me. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot

```
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('192.168.1.34', 80))
from_server = client.recv(4096)
client.close()
print from_server

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "CallManager2.py", line 4, in <module>
client.connect(('192.168.1.34', 80))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Is anything listening on `192.168.1.34:80`?

Comment: Can you provide the code of the server side ?

Comment: Will be good to send something to server before.

Comment: @KlausD. I don't know.

Comment: @ValentinM. I don't have the Code. It is written with another program. I only want to have a listener, who can receive transmitted data.

Comment: @KlausD. You will have trouble making a serveur you don't control send you something without asking (sending a request) it first.

Comment: @ValentinM. That doesn't matter for multiple reasons: 1. You can still listen. 2. There are servers sending a banner on connect. 3. The line with the `.recv()` is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from inability for your program to reach the server or other client.

Check that there is something listening to incoming connexions on the address you want to connect to.

Then you can check that the address you want to connect to is on the same network as your program.